# Open source libraries attribution in Android apps

Tags: android, open-source, licensing

Several Android apps (especially the ones by Google) feature a section with a list of open source libraries used in the app and for each of them, a full text of its licence. This usually involves the Apache License, which is used in most of the common Android libraries, such as ActionBarSherlock, ViewPagerIndicator, Guava etc.

- Is it mandatory to include such attribution in order to comply with the terms of the (Apache) license?
- How should this section look? If multiple libraries use the same license, is it necessary to duplicate the text of the license for each of them?
- Is it even necessary to include the whole text of the license, or is the sole copyright notice enough (see the appendix here: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)?
- Do the official Android developer guidelines feature some information on this topic (I failed to find any)?

Comment: Yes / Not Necessarily but mind differences (it is often easier to just duplicate) / Yes (at least this is sane as most if not any licenses do require that anyway which also makes sense) / IDK -- apart from your questions after you've listed them all, read them as well and look inside the terms if there are additional requirements you need to come after, e.g. `NOTICE` file with [the Apache-2.0 license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 5):

The Apache 2 license does not require attribution in their derived products advertising materials but I in my opinion it is often considered as "a nice thing to do" to support the developers of those libraries.

The attribution requirement *"'advertising clause'"* was  [removed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License#Version_history) in the Apache 1.1 license:

> The 1.1 version of the Apache License was approved by the ASF in 2000. The primary change from the 1.0 license is in the 'advertising clause' (section 3 of the 1.0 license); derived products are no longer required to include attribution in their advertising materials, only in their documentation.

Other open source software licenses have different requirements.